# How to use ActionListener in another class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, code-cleanup

I am cleaning my code. I read that I putting the `ActionListener` is another class is better. So that's what I did.

But in my `ActionListener`, everything works except at some point in the code, I got a `setSize(xx,xx)`. I worked before because it was in the same class. But not anymore. I've tried multiple solutions but I couldn't figure it out.

`ActionListener`:

```
public class ActionFrame implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Object src = e.getSource();

    if(src == Frame.Console_Bouton){
        System.out.println("Bouton console");
        if(getSize().getWidth() >= 750){
            /** If True (Retirer) */
            for(int i = 1090; i > 689; i--){
                setSize(i, 490);
                System.out.println("Rétractation du Frame");
            }
        }else{
            /** If False (Etirer) */
            for(int i = 689; i < 1090; i++){
                setSize(i, 490);
                System.out.println("Etirage du Frame");
            }
        }

            }

            ...
```

As for errors, there are none, it will just freeze the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing: possibly this is a case where extracting the `ActionListener` is *not* a great idea, since it uses a `private` method of your object.

Classes with generic/reusable functionality deserve to be on their own.  As long as they are intended for specific usage, it's not bad practice (at all!) to only put them as close as possible to the spot where they're used.  I can imagine that your `setSize` method is not part of your class' public interface, so the `ActionListener` is merely 'glue' to couple an event to your specific class.

In this case, you would create a 'tiny' line of glue:

```
abstract class ActionAdapter implements ActionListener {
}
...
frame.Console_Bouton.addActionListener(
    new ActionAdapter(){ // anonymous inner class 
      void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         ... // (no need to check source!)
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class as:

```
 ButtonAction implements actionListner
{
  //put the code above here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Good way of doing this is use **Callback mechanism**.

I have posted an answer in the same context here

> [JFrame in separate class, what about the ActionListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566948/jframe-in-separate-class-what-about-the-actionlistener?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

-- EDIT--

Get the source from `ActionEvent` then find its parent (get parent of parent if needed until you get the desired component that needs to be re sized) and call `setSize()` on it.

Comment: I think he's trying to follow the MVC pattern and, in that context, is moving the action listener from the View class to the Controller class. Callbacks are more inline with Multithreading.

Comment: @W.K.S Yes I am trying to follow the MVC.

Comment: I don't think so that Callbacks are more inline with Multithreading only. Its a pattern that can be any where in any technology.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create an instance of the View in the controller
2. Change the access modifier of `setSize(xx,yy)`method from `private` to `public`.
3. replace `setSize` in `actionPerformed()` with to `view.setSize(xx,yy)`.

Comment: which part is not needed?

Comment: Apparently, the class works allright without public `setSize`.  Therefor it's not needed to make it public.  Unless it's part of the 'published' functionality of that class, I think it's way better to keep it private.