# Pattern for nested callbacks

Tags: java, swing, callback

In this Swing example, I have two separate classes for the JFrame and the JMenuBar (Frame.class and MenuBar.class) and the Main.class, where I do the work. I'm using a callback to inform the Main.class about the user's selections.

As far as the MenuBar.class is concerned, this results in a nested callback (since I'm creating the MenuBar.class from the Frame.class).

My code is working, but I was wondering if there's a pattern for that.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Frame frame = new Frame() {
          @Override
          public void execute(Object obj) {
            System.out.println(obj);
          }
        };
      }
    });
  }
}

interface Callback {
  void execute(Object obj);
}

abstract class Frame extends JFrame implements Callback {
  Frame() {
    setTitle("GUI");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 150, 100);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Object obj) {
        redirectExecute(obj);
      }
    };
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        execute("Button");
      }
    });
    getContentPane().add(button);

    setVisible(true);
  }

  void redirectExecute(Object obj) {
    execute(obj);
  }
}

abstract class MenuBar extends JMenuBar implements Callback {
  MenuBar() {
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
    add(fileMenu);

    JMenuItem newFileItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Menu Item") {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        execute("Menu Item");
      }
    });
    fileMenu.add(newFileItem);
  }
}
```

Comment: you can't (bad idea) to call anything back to MainClass, code never will be works by default, sure is possible to create a constructor or getter its about design, btw please whats the goal

Comment: The first goal is to separate the GUI from the actual code, the second goal is to make the GUI more modular. Not sure if I understood the other part of your reply.

Comment: you have to accept that you haven't access back to MainClass (`public static void main(String[] args) {`), this class is designated to initailize code, to create an JVM instance, then after isn't accesible (is accessible but forgot about), I'm talking about void `execute()`, create a standard constructor (`public Main () {`) with `private variables` for `Objects`, then quite everything is possible

Comment: Then I either misunderstood what I was told [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/22566948/jframe-in-separate-class-what-about-the-actionlistener) or that was what you called a wrong idea?

Comment: there I can't see an advantage (my view), you will be limited by using this logics (here is reason why I called that wrong design), maybe in the case that you initialize another (and compiled) code, where do you mean is state to separate GUI and code how the Callback will help you with ..., again whats your goal (separate the GUI from the actual code == it can be whatever)

Comment: Basically, I have a standalone process (analyzing text files) and the GUI is only to set the parameters for that process and to kick off that process. So, there's a very limited number of events. I'm not a Java expert and I'm not a Swing expert for sure. My idea was to build a GUI upon the standalone process that can easily be detached.

Comment: (GUI upon the standalone process that can easily be detached)  == SystemTray (baloons/messagess) with JPopupMenu,

Comment: I have to admit that my project is a little bit more complex than implied, so I think you're right. In your approach, the Frame.class would expect a Main object (or whatever we call it) as a parameter. So would the MenuBar.class. Is that correct or is there a different pattern for that, too?